# Print RTF File (with dialog)

Tags: java, windows, printing, cross-platform, rtf

How can i open a standard print dialog (like in Word/Wordpad) to print an RTF Document from Java? (Cross Platform is preferred but not necessary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File("help.rtf"));
```

Comment: Wow. I thought that was going to be a long complicated method with all kinds of junk. That tells ya what I know! hey THANKS!

Comment: Sometimes it is just a matter of knowing the right method to call.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)